# Error in taking input from a file in a java

Tags: java

I am having an input file of  size 10^6 elements and i am taking the input.

```
    Input File:
  100000 //size of the array
   2 3 4 (so on as large as 10^6) 5 6 99
```

Code:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
 int n = in.nextInt();
 int[] p = new int[n];
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
     p[j]=in.nextInt();  // line 90
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at jobs.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:90)
```

Please help me where i am wrong

Comment: Basically, you don't actually have 10^6 elements... you might have *nearly* that many, but you don't have that many...

Comment: You can test if you have another integer by using `in.hasNext()`. Maybe if you dont have another integer you throw an exception of your own that tells more info such as how many elements were read and how many were expected.

Comment: Have you debugged it and single stepped through it. I bet you have a CRLF after the first size of array value in the input file, so you have to read in a line, then read each `nextInt()`.

Comment: just check with `5` as size of array and `1 2 3 4` as value in file       you will get `java.util.NoSuchElementException` that means your file don't have `5` elements as @Jon Skeet already mention it.

Comment: Then use `in.hasNextInt()` in you code somewhere to check if there is still an integer in the Scanner to be stored. That should solve it.